# LINQ to SQL not recognizing new associations?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have two projects using legacy databases with no associations between the tables. In one, if I create associations in the DBML file, I can reference the associations in LINQ like this:

```
From c In context.Cities Where c.city_name = "Portland" _
Select c.State.state_name
```

(assuming I added the link from `City.state_abbr` to `State.state_abbr` in the DBML file.)

In a different project that uses a different database, adding the association manually doesn't seem to give me that functionality, and I'm forced to write the LINQ query like this:

```
From c In context.Cities Where c.city_name = "Portland" _
Join s In context.States On c.state_abbr = s.state_abbr _
Select s.state_name
```

Any idea what I could be missing in the second project?

Note: These are completely contrived examples - the real source tables are nothing like each other, and are very cryptic.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?  I'm having the same trouble myself...

Comment: Found a fix for my problem, see the answer I posted:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like my problem was my tables didn't have primary keys in the second project. Like I stated, these are legacy tables, so I had to do the linking and primary key stuff in the Database Context instead of the database itself, and I just forgot to specify the primary keys the second time around. Frustrating when you don't spot it, but it makes sense now.

Answer (score 10):

Check your [Error List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33df3b7a(VS.80).aspx) page.  You might have something like the following in there:

> DBML1062: The Type attribute
>   '[ParentTable]' of the Association
>   element 'ParentTable_ChildTable' of
>   the Type element 'ChildTable' does not
>   have a primary key.  No code will be
>   generated for the association.

In which case all you should need to do is make sure that both tables have a primary key set and re-save the dbml file.  This will invoke the custom tool, which will in turn update the designer.cs file and create code for the association.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, when everything is configured correctly but still not working, the solution can be as simple as restarting Visual Studio.

I don't know why it happens sometimes, but I thought I should add this answer because having done some searching for a solution myself, it seems nobody has suggested this yet...

Comment: Geez I wish I had tried this sooner. I wasted about two hours trying to get this working and it was just VS being a jerk. Deleting the appData temp files and restarting VS worked for me.